# How to edit Mobile View only (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys I was wondering could someone help me here? I was trying to add some media queries so that my picture would be centers on mobile devices , my webpage is perfect on desktop view just on mobile it is lined to the right and will not move what so ever . How do I go about this??

I'm using sublime text and i got everything in diff files but here's what I have in my aboutme.html and stylesheet.css and you can also check out the site at oneal-kayla.com and resize the window to see what I mean thank you all so much! (I'm really new at this )

```
/*about me html */ 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Kayla O'Neal</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">


  <!--CDN Twitter Bootstrap stuff--> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">



</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li> 
        <li><a href="pdfresume.pdf">Resume</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<img src="fancyaboutme.png" class="center-block img-responsive"/>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



/*style sheet*/ 

body { 
    background:#3498db !important; 

}


.navbar .navbar-nav {  /*make the nav bar center on regular window*/ 
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {  /*make the nav bar center on mobile window*/ 
    text-align: center;

}

.navbar-default  /*navifgation bar*/ 
{
  background:#3498db !important; 
  border: none !important;



}
.navbar-nav > li a   /*link text*/ 
{
  color:white !important;
  text-align: center; 


}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover  /*color changes for links when hovered over*/ 
 {
 background:#2d8cca !important;  /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}

.navbar-default div.navbar-collapse
{
    border-top:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    text-align: center; 
}

.center-block
{
   margin-right:420px !important;


}
```

Comment: Why are adding the same question with different headings ?

Comment: I thought I deleted the previous question and added more tags sorry I was just trying to get help and this is the first time I've used this site so I thought that would help

Comment: Your image has whitespace on the left it seems

Comment: thank you i will look into that right now! sorry I didnt even think about that

Comment: thank you so much that was exactly the problem!

Comment: As a side note, I would put your stylesheet after bootstrap, or honestly concatenate them together using some kind of preprocessor. Less http requests will result in a faster page.